# Style not appearing on fixed div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that I want to appear on top of other divs and this is the code for it:

```
function displayMessage(content) {
        //content is a string
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.innerHTML = content;
        newElement.style.position = "fixed";
        newElement.style.left = "50%";
        newElement.style.right = "50%";
        newElement.style.top = "50%";
        newElement.style.bottom = "50%";
        newElement.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff33";
        newElement.style.border = "thick solid";
        newElement.style.display = "inline-block";
        newElement.style.zIndex = 100
}
```

When I do this the background color does not appear and the border is just a dot on the screen. However when I comment out the position everything works fine but my div is on the bottom of the screen.

```
function displayMessage(content) {
        //content is a string
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.innerHTML = content;
        //newElement.style.position = "fixed";
        newElement.style.left = "50%";
        newElement.style.right = "50%";
        newElement.style.top = "50%";
        newElement.style.bottom = "50%";
        newElement.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff33";
        newElement.style.border = "thick solid";
        newElement.style.display = "inline-block";
        newElement.style.zIndex = 100
}
```

How can I have the background color and border appear and still have the div's style be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the 'left' and 'right' properties to 50%, meaning you have forced the left of the div to be 50% of the screen width away from the left of the screen (ie, the middle of the screen) and the same for the right. So it cannot be any more than 0 pixels.

Try using a slightly lower value than 50%, or set it using a calc and a set width, for example:

```
newElement.style.left = "calc('50% - 100px')";
newElement.style.width = "200px";
```

This fixes the left position to 100px less than 50% of the screen width. So that combined with a 200px width will center it, if that is what you desire. Note that the 'right' style is no longer necessary. Then do the same for the top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks, this was the reason it wasn't working, I'm not sure how I'll fix it though because the width and height depends on the length of the content string

Comment: You might be stuck for the width, but for the height just don't set the height or bottom, and let the top be a fixed value so it can grow with the content

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the bottom:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newElement);
```

**Like This**

```
function displayMessage(content) {
    //content is a string
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.innerHTML = content;
    newElement.style.position = "fixed";
    newElement.style.left = "50%";
    newElement.style.right = "50%";
    newElement.style.top = "50%";
    newElement.style.bottom = "50%";
    newElement.style.backgroundColor = "#99ff33";
    newElement.style.border = "thick solid";
    newElement.style.display = "inline-block";
    newElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newElement);
}
```